# How to access Struts 2 action class properties directly

Tags: java, jsp, properties, struts2, ognl

I want to know if we populate action class properties, can we access them directly in the result JSP without assigning them to a form in the action class?

Comment: Please read the S2 docs; SO isn't meant as a replacement for due diligence. There are no form objects unless you decide to use one manually or via ModelDriven.

Comment: so you mean those properties i populate can directly access in a jsp using <%= name> if the action class have getName and setName?

Comment: No. Scriptlets are a completely different mechanism than bean access via tags or EL. Scriptlets have also been a Worst Practice for nearly a decade now.

Comment: thanks. btw when you mean by EL you mean <%= name> know

Comment: No, that's a scriptlet. I mean EL: `${name}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have the bean getter method defined properly . Say , if a property is named `id` and you have a method called `getId()` in your action. Then it can be accessed directly in the JSP as :

**[OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/ognl.html) expression:**

```
<s:property value="id"/>
```

OR

**JSTL expression:**

```
<c:out value="${action.id}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Struts2/XWork1 and its taglib is oriented towards OGNL, which is using
>   a `valueStack` for all action properties. These values are not direct
>   available for the expression language of JSP2.0/JSTL1.1.

To access it via OGNL you can use OGNL only in Struts tag attributes. For example

```
public String MyAction extends ActionSupport {
  private String myAttr;
  //getter and setter here
  ...


<s:set var="myAttrz" value="myAttr" scope="request"/>
${myAttrz} or ${myAttr} will just print out the value.
<%=request.getAttribute("myAttrz")%>
```

In the first tag the action attribute is accessed as OGNL expression
In the second line as JSTL expression.
In the third line scriptlets.

**References:**

- [Using Struts and XWork with JSP 2.0 and JSTL 1.1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Using+Struts+and+XWork+with+JSP+2.0+and+JSTL+1.1)
- [Application, Session, Request objects in JSP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Application%2C+Session%2C+Request+objects+in+jsp)
- [Can we use JSTL with the framework](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Can+we+use+JSTL+with+the+framework)

Comment: Action properties are available in JSP EL due to the request wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

one thing u can do is that initialize the properties in the **ModelDriven Class** which u want to be intialized whenever your action is called.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/model-driven.html