# Why Struts2 introduced the concept of ValueStack instead of using request attributes?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am just starting with Struts2 after completing JSP and Servlets. "Struts2 in Action" says the following for definition of `ValueStack`.

> Struts 2 uses the ValueStack as a storage area for all application domain data that will be needed during the processing of a request.Struts 2 uses the ValueStack as a storage area for all application domain data that will be needed during the processing of a request.

My question would be, why not bind the data objects as `request` object attributes from `Servlet API`? Why did they have to bring in a new data storage area per request (specifically per action)?

The definition states

> needed during processing of a **request**.

Feels more like the right place for it is request object.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/17135404/573032

Comment: I see you mean, that `ValueStack`'s action properties can be used as similar to `request`'s attributes in `EL` in JSPs. I will admit I did not know this, thanks. But my question is still not answered. Then why introduce a new concept of `ValueStack`?

Comment: This is already another question, so you should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767130/573032

Comment: Answers how `ValueStack` is useful. Doesn't answer "Why?". Why is it even a thing? `Request` object created by servlet api is also stored in servlet's `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Because that was how the original developers of WebWork did it--SO isn't the place to ask questions like that; you'd need to ask them directly. Ultimately the reason is to allow normalized access to a disparate number of data sources, e.g., a "virtual object", and to allow a hierarchical collection of objects to be accessed in a normalized way without having to manage it all by hand.

Comment: @Arun It is not a thing that is related to servlets. Struts allows you to abstract from the servlet environment by invoking a new concept that should be used by the applications. Why we use it because it's implemented by the framework and allowed us to use that thing on the view to access the model objects.